# Android error loading layout inflater from fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-sqlite

My app crashes immediately after I click on a searched activity. Here is the line of code below. I am viewing it from within a fragment; it's loading an SQLite database within the fragment. App crashes immediately; I click on search view in list item.

```
   public class HymnsFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
    SearchView.OnCloseListener {
private ListView mListView;
private SearchView searchView;
private CustomersDbAdapter mDbHelper;

private TextView inspectionDate;
private TextView customerText;
private TextView nameText;
private TextView addressText;
private TextView cityText;
private TextView stateText;
private TextView zipCodeText;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hymns,container,false);


    searchView = (SearchView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.search);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);

    mListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    // inspectionDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inspectionDate);
    //displayDate();

    mDbHelper = new CustomersDbAdapter(getActivity());
    mDbHelper.open();

    //Clean all Customers
    mDbHelper.deleteAllCustomers();
    //Add some Customer data as a sample
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn No", "Hymn Index", "Hymn name","", "Hymn Body","AUthor" , "90007");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn No", "Hymn Index", "Hymn name", "", "Hymn Body", "AUthor", "90015");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn No", "Hymn Index", "Hymn name", "", "Hymn Body", "AUthor", "90014");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn No", "Hymn Index", "Hymn name", "", "Hymn Body", "AUthor", "90026");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn No", "Hymn Index", "Hymn name", "", "Los Angeles", "AUthor", "90065");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn No", "Hymn Index", "4351 South Central Avenue", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90011");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn No", "Hymn Index", "975 West Jefferson", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90007");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn No", "Hymn Index", "2805 South Figueroa Street", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90007");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn No", "Hymn Index", "198 South Vermont Avenue", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90004");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn No", "Hymn Index", "504 West Olympic Boulevard", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90015");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn No", "Hymn Index", "975 West Jefferson", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90007");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn No", "Hymn Index", "504 West Olympic Boulevard", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90015");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn No", "Hymn Index", "504 West Olympic Boulevard", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90015");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn 1", "Hymn Index", "504 West Olympic Boulevard", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90015");
    mDbHelper.createCustomer("Hymn 1", "Hymn Index", "504 West Olympic Boulevard", "", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90015");




    return rootView;


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    showResults(newText + "*");
    return false;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    showResults(query + "*");
    return false;
}

public boolean onClose() {
    showResults("");
    return false;
}

private void showResults(String query) {

    Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.searchCustomer((query != null ? query.toString() : "@@@@"));

    if (cursor == null) {
        //
    } else {
        // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
        String[] from = new String[]{
                CustomersDbAdapter.KEY_CUSTOMER,
                CustomersDbAdapter.KEY_NAME,
                CustomersDbAdapter.KEY_ADDRESS,
                // CustomersDbAdapter.KEY_CITY,
                CustomersDbAdapter.KEY_STATE,
                CustomersDbAdapter.KEY_ZIP};

        // Specify the Corresponding layout elements where we want the columns to go
        int[] to = new int[]{
                R.id.scustomer,
                R.id.sname,
                R.id.saddress,
                //R.id.scity,
                R.id.sstate};
        // R.id.szipCode};

        // Create a simple cursor adapter for the definitions and apply them to the ListView
        SimpleCursorAdapter customers = new SimpleCursorAdapter(mListView.getContext(),R.layout.customerresult,cursor,from,to);
       // SimpleCursorAdapter customers = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.customerresult, cursor, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(customers);

        // Define the on-click listener for the list items
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
                String customer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("customer"));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
                String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
                String city = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("city"));
                String state = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("state"));
                String zipCode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("zipCode"));

                //Check if the Layout already exists
                LinearLayout customerLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.customerLayout);
                if (customerLayout == null) {
                    LinearLayout leftLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rightLayout);
                    View customerInfo = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customer_info, leftLayout, false);
                    leftLayout.addView(customerInfo);
                }


                    //Get References to the TextViews
                customerText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.customer);
                nameText = (TextView)view. findViewById(R.id.name);
                addressText = (TextView)view. findViewById(R.id.address);
                cityText = (TextView)view. findViewById(R.id.city);
                stateText = (TextView)view. findViewById(R.id.state);
                // zipCodeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zipCode);

                // Update the parent class's TextView
                customerText.setText(customer);
                nameText.setText(name);
                addressText.setText(address);
                cityText.setText(city);
                stateText.setText(state);
                //zipCodeText.setText(zipCode);

                searchView.setQuery("", true);
            }




        });
    }
}

private LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater() {
    return null;
}

}
```

Here is the log cat

```
  06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial     D/AndroidRuntime: procName from cmdline: com.example.vickie.mfmofficial
  06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime: in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.vickie.mfmofficial
  06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial D/AndroidRuntime: file written successfully with content: com.example.vickie.mfmofficial StringBuffer : ;com.example.vickie.mfmofficial
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.vickie.mfmofficial, PID: 12417
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.vickie.mfmofficial.HymnsFragment$1.onItemClick(HymnsFragment.java:152)
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
 06-27 00:15:16.745 12417-12417/com.example.vickie.mfmofficial E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
View customerInfo = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customer_info, leftLayout, false);
```

as you define `getLayoutInflater` method like this:

```
private LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater() {
    return null;
}
```

this obviously leads to the `NullPointerException`.

instead, try using something like this:

```
View customerInfo = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.customer_info, leftLayout, false);
```

or alternatively, you can modify the `getLayoutInflater` method so it doesn't return `null`:

```
private LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater() {
    return LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try it out

Comment: it still crashes after clicking on results from list view . Is there a way i can view d results information on a separate layout.